# YUI Compressor special comments adding semi-colon in JS

Tags: javascript, compression, comments, minify, yui-compressor

We've recently started using YUI Compressor (2.4.8) on our project. It works great, but we've noticed an issue when minifying JavaScript files which contain special comments.

It seems that YUI Compressor is adding a semi-colon after special comments. We completely removed all JS from the file, and only left the special comment in, and a semi-colon was still added.

Input:

```
/*!
 * WHY YOU ADD SEMI COLON?!
 */
```

Output:

```
/*!
 * WHY YOU ADD SEMI COLON?!
 */;
```

We searched online, but have been unable to find anybody who has had the same issue. It's also not an issue which affects CSS.

Is this a known issue with YUI Compressor? If so, what is the fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/126

It was tagged for the 2.4.9 release, but 18 months on v2.4.9 doesn't seem to be going anywhere in a hurry. I'm going to stick with the previous release.